# clearfix issue with <ul> <li> tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, clearfix

I use clearfix to clear the float. But the problem is ,there is a different height in `<li>` and `<div>`. `li.clearfix` height is 32px, but `div.clearfix` height is 18px. when I delete `.clearfix:before` , they are all the same.
But, when tried in bootstrap, it's failed.(I delete the `.clearfix:before` in bootstrap, but there is still a difference in height.)

```
<style>
.pull-left{
   float:left;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
</style> 
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">Hello</div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li class="clearfix"><div class="pull-left">hello</div></li>
</ul>
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/nevimop/p4HMS/

browsers (chrome safari ie10 , no problem in ff)

[image]

add this  `ul{list-style: none;}` the heights same.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please?

Comment: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N6sG7/). It looks strange indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Clearfix is used to force the parent of floated element(s) to receive a height, it does this by using `display: table` on `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to contain the margins of it's children and then uses `clear: both` on the `:after` element to clear it's own float. Together this allows us to apply a clearfix without needing additional markup.

If we force the `:before` pseudo element not to use `display: table` and instead use `display: inline` we can solve your issue of the unnecessary white-space.

```
li.clearfix:before {
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/72Nmy/

Comment: Do you have a technical explanation for this besides a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why do you set `:after` and `:before` as `display:table;` instead of `display:block;`

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/N6sG7/3/

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
  display:block;
  height:0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I used bootstrap in my code.`.clearfix` metioned in my code is copied from bootstrap.